# Preventing django from appending "_id" to a foreign key field

Tags: python, django

In django, if I set a field in a model to a foreign key, `"_id"` is appended to the name of that field. How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can set the field's [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#db-column) attribute to whatever you'd like.

Comment: It would be useful to have a setting like FK_AUTO_ID=False, I happen to be integrating with a legacy database having to write non-dry code such as basiscd = ForeignKey('...', db_column='basiscd', related_name='basiscd',. It's slightly annoying. Forms have auto_id=False available in a parallel scenario.

Comment: Or even better FK_AUTO_ID='cd' as in my case all FKs in this project hold this convention, which differs from Django's default (imagine FK_AUTO_ID='_id').

Comment: @Franki: You should be able to do what you want with an abstract model base class.

Comment: Working with a legacy db so i ran inspectdb. Surprised that it didn't auto-configure this for me.

Answer (score 5):

When using the foreign field in a model, Django creates two fields: One for the actual link, and one that references the other model.

```
class A(Model):
    i = IntegerField()

class B(Model):
    a = ForeignKey(A)
```

In `B` there is now two fields: `a` and `a_id`. `a_id` is the unique id as stored in the database, while `a` can be used to directly access the fields in `A`, like this:

```
b = B.objects.get(...)
b.a.i = 5;   # Set the field of A
b.a.save()   # Save A
```