# Save Username with models in database

Tags: django

```py
something=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='something', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Hi

when i'm using ForeignKey that model will save in database like :

```py
something_id
```

how i can change it to username or ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing django from appending "\_id" to a foreign key field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223519/preventing-django-from-appending-id-to-a-foreign-key-field)

Comment: Note that while you *can* do this, you absolutely shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`db_column=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

something=models.ForeignKey(
    get_user_model(),
    related_name='something',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    db_column='username'
)
```

You better use [**`get_user_model()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) since if you later change your mind on the user model you use, it will refer to the new model.

Note that the `ForeignKey` however will *not* save the `username` of the `User`. You can set the [**`to_field=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) for that:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

something=models.ForeignKey(
    get_user_model(),
    related_name='something',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    db_column='username',
    to_field='username'
)
```

Usually it is however advisable to use the primary key instead, since it makes the relations more uniform.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223519/preventing-django-from-appending-id-to-a-foreign-key-field)

The accepted answer: "You can set the field's [db-column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#db-column) attribute to whatever you'd like."